# Why isn't href working on my content?

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

For some reason, I can only do `<a href=""> </a>` on my content to make a link, when I try adding it to a whole div, it doesn't function at all. Does anyone know whats going on, I'm trying to make `<div class="content">` function as a link. So far `<div class="content" href="index.html">` didn't work. Am I coding something wrong here or is there an error I'm missing? Thanks.

```css
body {
background-color: #323232;
width: 100%;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
font-family: Lato;
}

nav a {
color: #fff;
text-decoration: none;
padding: 20px 25px;
display: inline-block;
}

.fixed-header, .fixed-footer {
background: #333;
color: #fff;
width: 100%;
position: fixed;
text-align: center;
z-index: 10;
background-color: #202020;
}

.fixed-header {
top: 0;
}

.fixed-footer {
bottom: 0;
padding: 20px 0px;
}

.fixed-header a:hover {
color: #c1c1c1;
}

.fixed-footer a {
color: #fff;
font-weight: lighter;
text-decoration: none;
}


.group-content {
max-width: 960px;
text-align: center;
width: 75%;
margin: 100px auto;
display: flex;
flex-wrap: wrap;
justify-content: space-evenly;

}

.group-content h3 {
margin-top: 10px;
font-weight: normal;
font-size: 20px;
color: white;
}

.group-content p {
margin-top: 3px;
font-weight: lighter;
font-size: 20px;
color: white;
}

.content {
width: 30%;
background-color: #202020;
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
padding: 20px 0 20px 0;
align-items: center;
margin-top: 20px;
}

.content >* {
max-width: 200px;
text-align: center;
margin: 0;
}

@font-face {
font-family: "Lato";
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
src: url('fonts/Lato-Regular.eot'),
src: url('fonts/Lato-Regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
url('fonts/Lato-Regular.ttf') format('truetype'),
url('fonts/Lato-Regular.woff') format('woff'),
url('fonts/Lato-Regular.woff2') format('woff2');
}

@font-face {
font-family: "Lato";
font-weight: bold;
font-style: normal;
src: url('fonts/Lato-Bold.eot'),
src: url('fonts/Lato-Bold.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
url('fonts/Lato-Bold.ttf') format('truetype'),
url('fonts/Lato-Bold.woff') format('woff'),
url('fonts/Lato-Bold.woff2') format('woff2');
}

@font-face {
font-family: "Lato";
font-weight: lighter;
font-style: normal;
src: url('fonts/Lato-Light.eot'),
src: url('fonts/Lato-Light.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
url('fonts/Lato-Light.ttf') format('truetype'),
url('fonts/Lato-Light.woff') format('woff'),
url('fonts/Lato-Light.woff2') format('woff2');
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

    <html lang="en">

    <head>
    <title>Kumo99.cf</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    <link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico">
    </head>

    <body>

    <div class="fixed-header">
    <nav>
     <a href="index.html">HOME</a>
     <a href="projects.html">PROJECTS</a>
     <a href="about.html">ABOUT</a>
    </nav>
    </div>

    <div class="fixed-footer">
    <a href="https://steamcommunity.com/id/kumo99">Made by Kumo © 2018</a>
    </div>

    <div class="group-content", href="index.html">
    <div class="content">
     <img src="images/arma.png">
     <h3>Arma 3: Exile Server</h3>
     <p>A project for improving the exile mod.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="content">
     <img src="images/soon.png">
     <h3>Reserved Space</h3>
     <p>Reserved space for future projects</p>
    </div>

    <div class="content">
     <img src="images/soon.png">
     <h3>Reserved Space</h3>
     <p>Reserved space for future projects</p>
    </div>

    <div class="content">
     <img src="images/soon.png">
     <h3>Reserved Space</h3>
     <p>Reserved space for future projects</p>
    </div>

    <div class="content">
     <img src="images/soon.png">
     <h3>Reserved Space</h3>
     <p>Reserved space for future projects</p>
    </div>

    <div class="content">
     <img src="images/soon.png">
     <h3>Reserved Space</h3>
     <p>Reserved space for future projects</p>
    </div>
    </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Please add appropriate CSS code for link element (a).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `<div>` cannot have the `href` attribute. `href` can only function on an `<a>`nchor, `<link>`, or `<base>`. A valid way to make all of those `<div>`s linked to `index.html` is to wrap `.group-content` with an `<a>`nchor and then style the `<a>`nchor so it behaves like a `<div>`.

```
<a href='index.html' style='display:block; text-decoration:none'>
  <div class='group-content'>...</div>
</a>
```

### Demo

```css
body {
background-color: #323232;
width: 100%;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
font-family: Lato;
}

nav a {
color: #fff;
text-decoration: none;
padding: 20px 25px;
display: inline-block;
}

.fixed-header, .fixed-footer {
background: #333;
color: #fff;
width: 100%;
position: fixed;
text-align: center;
z-index: 10;
background-color: #202020;
}

.fixed-header {
top: 0;
}

.fixed-footer {
bottom: 0;
padding: 20px 0px;
}

.fixed-header a:hover {
color: #c1c1c1;
}

.fixed-footer a {
color: #fff;
font-weight: lighter;
text-decoration: none;
}


.group-content {
max-width: 960px;
text-align: center;
width: 75%;
margin: 100px auto;
display: flex;
flex-wrap: wrap;
justify-content: space-evenly;

}

.group-content h3 {
margin-top: 10px;
font-weight: normal;
font-size: 20px;
color: white;
}

.group-content p {
margin-top: 3px;
font-weight: lighter;
font-size: 20px;
color: white;
}

.content {
width: 30%;
background-color: #202020;
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
padding: 20px 0 20px 0;
align-items: center;
margin-top: 20px;
}

.content >* {
max-width: 200px;
text-align: center;
margin: 0;
}

@font-face {
font-family: "Lato";
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
src: url('fonts/Lato-Regular.eot'),
src: url('fonts/Lato-Regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
url('fonts/Lato-Regular.ttf') format('truetype'),
url('fonts/Lato-Regular.woff') format('woff'),
url('fonts/Lato-Regular.woff2') format('woff2');
}

@font-face {
font-family: "Lato";
font-weight: bold;
font-style: normal;
src: url('fonts/Lato-Bold.eot'),
src: url('fonts/Lato-Bold.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
url('fonts/Lato-Bold.ttf') format('truetype'),
url('fonts/Lato-Bold.woff') format('woff'),
url('fonts/Lato-Bold.woff2') format('woff2');
}

@font-face {
font-family: "Lato";
font-weight: lighter;
font-style: normal;
src: url('fonts/Lato-Light.eot'),
src: url('fonts/Lato-Light.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
url('fonts/Lato-Light.ttf') format('truetype'),
url('fonts/Lato-Light.woff') format('woff'),
url('fonts/Lato-Light.woff2') format('woff2');
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

    <html lang="en">

    <head>
    <title>Kumo99.cf</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">

    <link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico">
    </head>

    <body>

    <div class="fixed-header">
    <nav>
     <a href="index.html">HOME</a>
     <a href="projects.html">PROJECTS</a>
     <a href="about.html">ABOUT</a>
    </nav>
    </div>

    <div class="fixed-footer">
    <a href="https://steamcommunity.com/id/kumo99">Made by Kumo © 2018</a>
    </div>
    
   <a href="index.html" style='display:block;text-decoration:none'>
    <div class="group-content">
    <div class="content">
     <img src="images/arma.png">
     <h3>Arma 3: Exile Server</h3>
     <p>A project for improving the exile mod.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="content">
     <img src="images/soon.png">
     <h3>Reserved Space</h3>
     <p>Reserved space for future projects</p>
    </div>

    <div class="content">
     <img src="images/soon.png">
     <h3>Reserved Space</h3>
     <p>Reserved space for future projects</p>
    </div>

    <div class="content">
     <img src="images/soon.png">
     <h3>Reserved Space</h3>
     <p>Reserved space for future projects</p>
    </div>

    <div class="content">
     <img src="images/soon.png">
     <h3>Reserved Space</h3>
     <p>Reserved space for future projects</p>
    </div>

    <div class="content">
     <img src="images/soon.png">
     <h3>Reserved Space</h3>
     <p>Reserved space for future projects</p>
    </div>
    </div>
    </a>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the href information, it works perfectly.

Answer (score 3):

'href' attribute wont work on 'div' element. 'href' attribute would only work on 'a' tag. So wrap the 'div' element inside 'a' element.

```html
<a href = "index.html">
  <div class ="group-content">
  <!-- Insert your code here -->
  </div>
</a>
```

Or you can wrap 'a' element inside 'div' element

```html
    <div class ="group-content">    
      <a href = "index.html">
        <!-- Insert your code here -->
      </a>
    </div>
```

Comment: This seems like the most suitable answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your code of

```
<div class="content" href="index.html">
```

will not work as you want it to. Instead you need to program the behavior with Javascript:

```
<div class="content" onclick="window.location.href='index.html';">
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```html
<a href="https://steamcommunity.com/id/kumo99" target="_blank">Made by Kumo © 2018</a>
```